# R: dataframe to separate new column in key-value pairs

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, tidyr

How to concatenate R dataframe rows to a separate new column as key-value pairs. I tried few things but unsuccessful so far.

```
      city  rev qty   zip
1  Atlanta 63.0   1 45987
2 New York 10.6   1 12686
3  Atlanta 12.0   1 74268
4    Tampa  3.0   1 33684
```

convert the above dataframe to

```
      city  rev qty   zip   key_value
1  Atlanta 63.0   1 45987   city=Atlanta;rev=63.0;qty=1;zip=45987
2 New York 10.6   1 12686   city=New York;rev=10.60;qty=1;zip=12686
3  Atlanta 12.0   1 74268   city=Atlanta;rev=12.0;qty=1;zip=74268
4    Tampa  3.0   1 33684   city=Tampa;rev=3.0;qty=1;zip=33684
```

Comment: [`?paste`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/paste)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `paste` the values and column names rowwise using `apply` -

```
df$key_value <- apply(df, 1, function(x) 
                      paste(names(x), x, sep = '=', collapse = ';'))
df

#     city  rev qty   zip                             key_value
#1 Atlanta 63.0   1 45987 city=Atlanta;rev=63.0;qty=1;zip=45987
#2 NewYork 10.6   1 12686 city=NewYork;rev=10.6;qty=1;zip=12686
#3 Atlanta 12.0   1 74268 city=Atlanta;rev=12.0;qty=1;zip=74268
#4   Tampa  3.0   1 33684   city=Tampa;rev= 3.0;qty=1;zip=33684
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_c(cur_column(), "=", .), 
    .names = "{.col}_new")) %>% 
   unite(key_value, ends_with('new'), sep=";")
      city  rev qty   zip                              key_value
1  Atlanta 63.0   1 45987    city=Atlanta;rev=63;qty=1;zip=45987
2 New York 10.6   1 12686 city=New York;rev=10.6;qty=1;zip=12686
3  Atlanta 12.0   1 74268    city=Atlanta;rev=12;qty=1;zip=74268
4    Tampa  3.0   1 33684       city=Tampa;rev=3;qty=1;zip=33684
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(city = c("Atlanta", "New York", "Atlanta", "Tampa"
), rev = c(63, 10.6, 12, 3), qty = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), zip = c(45987L, 
12686L, 74268L, 33684L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```